# declaration of const pointer vs declaration of const integer

Tags: c, variables, memory, constants, pc-lint

Anyone can explain me what is the difference between two blocks of code below:

```
func1 (...)
{
    int32_t index;
    const int32_t *p;
    p =& (index);
}
func2 (...)
{
     const int32_t s;
     s=10;  
}
```

It is possible to declare a const pointer and then assign a value to it but it is not possible to declare a normal variable and then assign a value to it. Can somebody explain this to me?

I get a pc-lint error that I have to declare the const variable inside the function but I cannot do it. How can I get rid of this error?

Thank you so much.

Comment: You can add "number_of_stars + 1" `const` to a declaration; the `const` applies to whatever is on its immediate right: `int [const] * [const] * ... [const] foo = value;`

Comment: `const int32_t s; s = 10;` compiler error ... `int32_t * const p; p = NULL;` compiler error

Answer (score 3):

That's because they're *not* doing the same thing (using `T` as type since I'm basically lazy):

```
const T *p; // non-const pointer to const T.
const T s;  // const T.
```

It *may* help to think of the former as binding like `[const T] [*p]`.

If you want a `const` *pointer,* you do that with one of:

```
T * const p;         // const pointer to non-const T, [T*] [const p]
const T * const p;   // const pointer to const T, [const T*] [const p].
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int i=0;
const int *p=&i;
*p = 10; /*error*/
```

This is `incorrect`, because p is declared `pointer to constant int`, so you cannot change the integer value p points to, via p.

```
int i=0;
int const *p=&i;
*p = 10; /* i will be 10 */
```

This is `correct`, because p is declared `constant pointer to int`, so you can change the integer value p points to, via p.

```
int i=0;
const int const *p;
p = &i;  /*error*/
*p = 10; /*error*/
```

This is `incorrect`, because p is declared `constant pointer to constant int`, so you cannot change neither the integer value p points to, via p, nor the value of p after it's declared.

Answer (score 0):

> "It is possible to declare a `const` pointer and then assign a value to it..."

`const int32_t *p` is not a `const` pointer to `int32_t`. It is a non-`const` pointer to `const` `int32_t`.

`int32_t * const p;` would give you a `const` pointer to `int32_t`. Take care of that the `const` specifier is at the right side of the `*` declarator.

You can modify the pointer itself however you want because it is not `const`, so `p = &(index);` is fine. Note that the parenthesis are redundant.

> "...but it is not possible to declare a normal variable and then assign a value to it."

`const int32_t s;` is not a "normal modifiable" variable. It is declared with `const`. You cannot assign a `const` variable after its definition/initialization. You can only initialize it once at its definition.

Thus, using

```
 const int32_t s;
 s = 10;
```

gives you of course an error.

> How can I get rid of this error?

Initialize `s` at its definition:

```
const int32_t s = 10;
```